# Programming principles and practice using C++ error: constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

In Stroustrup's "Programming principles and practice" book, there's an example of `constexpr` like this:

```
void user(Point p1)
{
    Point p2 {10,10};
    Point p3 = scale(p1); // OK: p3 == {100,8}; run-time evaluation is fine
    constexpr Point p4 = scale(p2); // p4 == {100,8}
    constexpr Point p5 = scale(p1); // error: scale (p1) is not a constant
                                    // expression
    constexpr Point p6 = scale(p2); // p6 == {100,8}
    // . . .
}
```

- But think he is mistaken: `p2`although initialized with constant expression arguments (literals here 10, 10) it is not a `constexpr` object because it is not declared so.

So normally `p4` and `p6` are in error here: (cannot use `p2` in a constant expression). it is like `p1`.

- To correct it:

  ```
   constexpr Point p2{10, 10};
  ```

Comment: Which is your question?

Comment: @MarcoBeninca: Is it a mistake in the book?

Comment: Note that Stroustrup's books have plenty of typos. The errata only mention those he doesn't consider obvious.

Comment: how is `scale` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know who is really good at telling you if something is allowed as a `constexpr`? Your compiler. https://godbolt.org/z/4Kdocx83v

And you are right, it's broken.

Comment: compiler `constexpr` support isn't stable (they're chasing a moving target), so compiler bugs are not uncommon.  Therefore while it's useful to know what a particular compiler thinks of a particular piece of code, you shouldn't accept it as absolute truth.

Comment: @BenVoigt Nothing is ever absolute. But I doubt there is still much happening with constexpr and c++11. The moving target is in support for c++20 and the STL.